# miner gets the right to get 0.05% as tramsacton fee when the coin trensfered

Tags: mining-pools, transaction-fees

miner gets the right to get 0.05% as transacton fee when the coin trensfered.

But, if i start mining at the mining pool, who gets 0.05% of transaction fee?

the pool? or me?

Comment: Your question's assumption is **incorrect**!  There is no such thing as a 0.05% transaction fee or any percentage!  The transaction fee is based on the number of inputs and outputs not the amount!  If you create a transaction with only 1 input and 1 output to send 10 million bitcoins it will have the minimum transaction fee.  If you send .001 bitcoins in a transaction with 100 inputs and 100 outputs you will have a very large transaction fee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the pool. BTCGuild for example also distributes the fees fairly. Eventually the fixed mining reward (25BTC now) is going to go down and disappear and everything will have to be paid from the transaction fees. So if they don't already, pools will have to pay those out at some point.